# Accessing functions of a class that implement an Interface that are not part of the Interface

Tags: c++, unit-testing, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I am writing an application in c++.
I have an interface defined with various functions:

```
class ITest
{
public:
        virtual void x()=0;
        virtual void y()=0;
}
```

I then have a class that implements this interface, along with additional functions:

```
class NewClass: public ITest
{
public:
    virtual void x();
    virtual void y();
    // new function not defined in interface
    virtual void z();
}
```

I now want to access all of these 3 functions from my unit tests.
Currently I am using:

```
ITest* pTest;
```

which will only give me access to the 2 functions defined in the interface.
How can I also gain access to function z() without defining it in the interface?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you cannot do that since accessing a function not defined in the interface through a pointer to an object of the interface type, would defeat the purpose of having an interface!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NewClass* p = dynamic_cast<NewClass*>(pTest);
if(p==0)
{
   //error!!! pTest's dynamic type wasn't NewClass*
}
else
{
   p->z();
}
```

Instead of `dynamic_cast`, you can use `static_cast`. But if `pTest`'s dynamic type is not actually `NewClass*` you'll get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use a NewClass* or cast to one if it is one.

Answer (score 0):

As it is an unit test, you control the line where the class is created.

Now don't do:

```
ITest* pTest = new NewClass();
```

but do:

```
NewClass* pTest = new NewClass();
```

and you can use `pTest->z()` without problems.